# Convert an Array to PyTorch IValue on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, pytorch

Simple question.

I have an array of `int`s in Android (Kotlin). I need to convert it to an `org.pytorch.IValue`. I believe that such a conversion can be done, but I can't figure out how to do it. This is my array

`val array = Array(34)     { IntArray(1) }`

How do I get this wrapped in an `IValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this by way of the Tensor object. The Tensor class has a static method for creating tensor buffers, such as by `Tensor.allocateIntBuffer()`. The argument for that call accepts the number of elements that the buffer will contain. The `.put()` method on the buffer places items within the buffer. Once the buffer is populated, it can be converted to an `IValue` with `IValue.from(sourceTensor)`.